# jQuery - Get value from c# dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, dictionary

I am new to jQuery. I have a jQuerypiece of code which assign PAN Name to label which return from c# dictionary after conversion in JSON. When I getting value in alert(Bold Line). It is showing undefined.

Below is my code.

```js
                    success: function (data) {
                        var msgi = data.MSG;
                        var panno;
                        if (msgi != "A" && msgi != "B") {
                            alert(msgi); ////// Here undefined is showing
                            $("#Item3_PANNumber").focus();
                            $("#Item3_PANNumber").val('');
                        }                         

                    }
```

```html
/////// This is last part of method.

                            if (words.Length > 0)
                            {
                                PANCard pc = new PANCard();

                                if (words[0] == "1" && words[2] == "E")
                                {
                                    pc.PANNumber = words[1];
                                    pc.LastName = words[3];
                                    pc.FirstName = words[4];
                                    pc.MiddleName = words[5];
                                    pc.Title = words[6];
                                    pc.LastUpdated = words[7]; ////DateTime.ParseExact(words[7], @"d/M/yyyy", culture);

                                    var panno = pc.Title + " " + pc.FirstName + " " + pc.MiddleName + " " + pc.LastName;
                                    Returndict.Add("MSG", "B");
                                    return Json(panno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                                }
                            }
```

Your help may appreciated.

Thanks
Nandkumar S.

Comment: Could you please make a reduced code example? (See: http://www.sscce.org/) I'm fairly sure most of the code you posted is not really relevant to the problem. Also consider stepping into both the C# code and the JS code in a debugger to see what value you're returning to the webpage, and what's happening at the line of code where you get the error.

Comment: Dear millimoose,

Thianks for your reply. I have shorten the code.

Comment: You're never actually returning `ReturnDict` from your C# code, or `pc`, only the `panno` string. Unless it's put into the JSON response outside the code shown.

Comment: **Thanks** millimoose. It is been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a class for response:**

```js
1. Create a response class

public class JsonReaponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } 
    public object Data { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

2. Use a response class with object

JsonReaponse reaponse = new JsonReaponse();
if (words.Length > 0)
{
    PANCard pc = new PANCard();
    if (words[0] == "1" && words[2] == "E")
    {
        pc.PANNumber = words[1];
        pc.LastName = words[3];
        pc.FirstName = words[4];
        pc.MiddleName = words[5];
        pc.Title = words[6];
        pc.LastUpdated = words[7]; ////DateTime.ParseExact(words[7], @"d/M/yyyy", culture);

        var panno = pc.Title + " " + pc.FirstName + " " + pc.MiddleName + " " + pc.LastName;
        reaponse.Message = "Your Message";
        reaponse.Data = panno;
        return Json(reaponse, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

            
3. In jQuery

success: function (res) {
    var msgi = res.Message;
    var panno = res.Data;
    if (msgi != "A" && msgi != "B") {
        alert(msgi); ////// Here undefined is showing
        $("#Item3_PANNumber").focus();
        $("#Item3_PANNumber").val('');
    }                         
}
```

Comment: Thanks Govind,

This helped me a lot... :)